# Фрейм во всю страницу

Tags: html

Я поместил iframe внутрь страницы.

```
<html>
<body>
   <iframe src="http://ya.ru/" width="100%" height="100%"/>   
</body>
</html>
```

Вроде все должно растянуться до упора, но рамка по краям осталась (смотрю в Хроме). Как ее убрать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://ya.ru/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder = "no"/>
```